# How to use stored procedures with Django backend?

Tags: django, stored-procedures, django-rest-framework

I have created a stored procedure in SSMS for the query SELECT * FROM TABLE and now I want to create a Django API and test it. What is the entire procedure?

My script from SQL Stored Procedure:

```
USE [test]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[spGetAll]     ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Author,,Name>
-- Create date: <Create Date,,>
-- Description: <Description,,>
-- =============================================
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetAll] 
    
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SELECT * from app_comment
END
GO
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to call a stored procedure do the following-

```py
from django.db import connection

def dictfetchall(cursor):
    columns = [col[0] for col in cursor.description]
    return [
        dict(zip(columns, row))
        for row in cursor.fetchall()
    ]

with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.callproc("stored_procedure", [arg1, arg2, arg3])
    data = dictfetchall(cursor)
```

For reference view [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/sql/#calling-stored-procedures)

Answer (score 0):

I could not get alamshafi2263's answer to work, giving various syntax errors. My procedure takes a parameter but returns no value.
Here is what i used successfully:

```
from django.db import connection
local_cursor = connection.cursor()
call_definition = f'call public.ap_update_holding_value({transaction_id})'
local_cursor.execute(call_definition)
```

In the above transaction_id is the parameter value.
Tested with Django==3.1.13, psycopg2==2.9.1